# lightswitch create cusom table/list with javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I need to create a table or list in lightswitch with javascript in the HTML-CLient filled with my own custom data, which does not come from a query.

I died already try to create the list using `<ul><li>` or `<table><tr><td>` tags but it does not use the default lightswitch css. Is there some other way than just copying the styles?

Thanks!

Comment: What solutions have you already tried? Please do some basic research before posting to SO with general questions like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try your luck with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2, specifically the table control.

[MSDN - Introduction to jQuery for App Customization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/01/28/introduction-to-jquery-for-customization-in-cloud-business-apps-kevin-mehlhaff.aspx)

> "When data is displayed in a table in a LightSwitch app, it uses the jQuery Mobile table control to automatically adjust its display based on the resolution of the device."